# Formatting problem in the 'related questions' bar

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problems with TeX rendering today](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6344/problems-with-tex-rendering-today)

There seems to be some kind of rendering bug in the 'related questions' bar, to wit:

[image]

The question linked to is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63273/how-do-you-pronounce-mathbbq-sqrt2?rq=1), and I believe that the mathematics should render like this:

[image]

Comment: which question are you viewing?

Comment: Ack, I don't know. Sorry. I don't seem to be able to reproduce the bug now. If it helps, I am using Windows 7 and browsing with Chrome Version 22.0.1229.94 m

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6344/problems-with-tex-rendering-today

Comment: @Chris: I solved that issue, see my answer on the related thread.